# Deactivate Chromium Download in build-administration.sh

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When executing build-administration.sh in docker (dockware image) there is a step where chromium get downloaded.

```
> puppeteer@13.7.0 install /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/puppeteer
```

> node install.js

Downloading Chromium r982053 - 150.3 Mb [====================] 100% 0.0s
Chromium (982053) downloaded to /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053

this absolutely slows down this build process. Is there a way to deactivate this download and use the already downloaded version of earlier runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the Chromium download by setting the PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD environment variable to 1.

For example by adding this to your 'build-administration.sh'

```
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=1
```

Two other optimalizations that you can use to speed up the build process are:

```
export SHOPWARE_ADMIN_BUILD_ONLY_EXTENSIONS=1
export DISABLE_ADMIN_COMPILATION_TYPECHECK=1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an environment variable you can set to skip the download.

```bash
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=1
```

Comment: Why does it download it by default in the admin build?